# iCloud Drive Documents Folder Not Syncing After High Sierra New Install

Tags: macos, icloud, finder, ssd, high-sierra

Today I have just got an SSD installed in my Mac Mini 2012 via an authorised service. I did not ask for data migration because I wanted to start "fresh".

After the initial boot, I found out they have put an image of the New MacOS High Sierra. I followed the installation wizard.

Now, after entering my iCloud details I noticed email accounts were setup, Photos started syncing, etc. All good.

*However when I open the finder and go to the `Documents` folder, it's **empty**.*

***Is there a way to manually trigger the sync process?***

Thank you

PS FYI: The SSD was shown as APFS and I had to manually enable FileVault.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iCloud Drive Won't Sync on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313716/icloud-drive-wont-sync-on-mac)

Comment: @DManokhin - not a dupe.  This question is about *one particular folder* not syncing while the others do.  What you pointed was syncying is not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313716/icloud-drive-wont-sync-on-mac).

Go to Terminal and type:

```
killall bird
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support
rm -rf CloudDocs
```

then immediately restart. Wait an hour or two.