# Sync with icloud doesn't work

Tags: macos, icloud

The sync between icloud and my ipad and my mac doesn't, for all services (icloud drive, Ibooks...)

My mac is running Catalina 10.15.3
My ipad is running Ios 13.3.1

Nothing is sync on the devices but the data are available via icloud.com.

Here's what I tried:

- Sign off and sign in from I cloud.
- Restart many times
- Kill the bird process and deleting the ~/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs as described here  [iCloud Drive Won't Sync on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313716/icloud-drive-wont-sync-on-mac)

Thanks

Here are the bird logs (via brctl log):

```
ERR  2020-03-17 20:45:57.392+0100] Terminal[8466]  Failed getting container for URL: <private>, error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=7 UserInfo={NSDescription=<private>, NSFilePath=<private>
[note 2020-03-18 01:19:55.876+0100] revisiond[245]  Cache delete asked us to reclaim <private> with urgency 1
[note 2020-03-18 01:19:56.881+0100] revisiond[245]  Cache delete asked us to reclaim <private> with urgency 1
[note 2020-03-18 01:19:56.942+0100] revisiond[245]  Cache delete asked us to reclaim <private> with urgency 1
[note 2020-03-18 01:19:57.014+0100] revisiond[245]  Cache delete asked us to reclaim <private> with urgency 1
[WARN 2020-03-18 17:52:12.595+0100] revisiond[245]  This volume is runnning "<private>" which is not supported
[WARN 2020-03-18 17:52:12.595+0100] revisiond[245]  This volume is runnning "<private>" which is not supported
[CRIT 2020-03-18 18:51:36.306+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[ERR  2020-03-18 18:52:41.542+0100] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[22633]  can't find image with size <private> for <private>
[CRIT 2020-03-18 18:52:41.543+0100] com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[22633]  Provider returned error from domain BRCloudDocsErrorDomain which is unsupported. Supported error domains are N
[note 2020-03-18 18:54:18.039+0100] revisiond[245]  device 1000015 had a metainfo file
[note 2020-03-18 18:54:19.197+0100] revisiond[245]  device 1000015 UUID matches metadata
[note 2020-03-18 18:54:19.214+0100] revisiond[245]  Quitting throttled mode on device 16777237
[note 2020-03-18 18:54:19.327+0100] revisiond[245]  Library on device 1000015, loaded status <private>
[ERR  2020-03-18 18:55:13.609+0100] Finder[550]  -[BRFrameworkContainerHelper br_capabilityToMoveFromURL:toNewParent:error:]: (passed to caller) error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=6 UserInf
[ERR  2020-03-18 18:55:16.531+0100] Finder[550]  -[BRFrameworkContainerHelper br_capabilityToMoveFromURL:toNewParent:error:]: (passed to caller) error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=6 UserInf
[CRIT 2020-03-18 18:55:25.728+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[ERR  2020-03-18 18:56:08.074+0100] Finder[550]  -[BRFrameworkContainerHelper br_capabilityToMoveFromURL:toNewParent:error:]: (passed to caller) error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=6 UserInf
[CRIT 2020-03-18 19:00:31.546+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[CRIT 2020-03-18 19:05:32.194+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[CRIT 2020-03-18 19:11:06.303+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[ERR  2020-03-18 19:15:50.197+0100] bird[583]  fts_read() failed for path <private> [2: No such file or directory]
[CRIT 2020-03-18 19:15:50.914+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[CRIT 2020-03-18 19:16:36.120+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[CRIT 2020-03-18 19:22:06.120+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[CRIT 2020-03-18 19:27:31.578+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[CRIT 2020-03-18 19:32:35.818+0100] bird[583]  UNREACHABLE: can't open <private>
[ERR  2020-03-18 19:36:13.390+0100] Finder[550]  -[BRFrameworkContainerHelper br_capabilityToMoveFromURL:toNewParent:error:]: (passed to caller) error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=6 UserInf
```

Answer (score 0):

I bought a new M1 Mac and after setting it up, it just wouldn't sync iCloud from a fresh install. All my other devices worked just fine. After many many many attempts I just tried something randomly and it worked!

**Actual solution**

1. I renamed the laptop under System Preference -> Sharing
2. Disabled iCloud Drive and re-enabled it

**Apple support sucks**

I contacted Apple for their support as I ran out of ideas. They were very nice at first and tried to help me with my problem. Now I'm pretty tech-savvy. I used to work in IT and now I work as an iOS/macOS developer. So it became pretty clear to me that their staff is pretty useless. Still I listened and followed their pointless instructions exactly. Eventually they told me they have to reach out to higher support and contact me next week. I never heard back from them.

I suspect they bought time because my laptop was still under the return policy. As soon as the return policy expired, they stopped their efforts to help me. Pretty low in my opinion.