# Is anyone having problems with iCloud not syncing?

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization

I have an M1 MacBook Air that doesn't stay in sync with files stored in iCloud that have been created or edited on other machines.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @sevenTool I would suggest that you simply split up your text and remove the "answer part" from it - and then post it as an answer to your question. [It is completely OK to answer your own question.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) That way it is correctly split up in question/answers, and people can upvote your answer.

Comment: Also, this might be a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313716/icloud-drive-wont-sync-on-mac

Comment: Thanks. It's related, but IMO a better work around.

Comment: @sevenTool Both methods accomplish the same thing at the end.

Comment: The real question (for Apple) is why these machinations? It's a problem that has been happening for years in what seems to be isolated cases. Personally never had the issue until this new machine was delivered.

Answer (score 4):

To force iCloud to sync, open Activity Monitor and "kill the bird". That is, stop the bird process aka the BIRD daemon. It restarts on its own and the sync occurs.

[image]

A pain, yes, but easier than logging out of the user account and logging back in.

Comment: Thanks it worked but why do we have to keep killing that bird all the time?